# Create one unified ditamap by replacing all maprefs with actual topicrefs

Tags: xml, xslt, dita

I have a set of ditamaps that are called recursively to create a single unified book. However, due to some issues with how chunking works in DITA, I would like to process the map files to replace all maprefs with actual topicrefs. I seek help in developing an XSLT to achieve this.
For example, the current implementation is:

```
map a
|_____map a1
|_____map a2
      |_______map a21
      |_______map a22
              |_______map a221
```

This is achieved using maprefs to map a1, map a2, map a21...

What I need is one single map (Map_unified.ditamap) with all the topic refs in map a1, map a2, map a21, map a22, and map a221.

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: If this helped, can you mark the correct answer please?

Answer (score 1):

There are ways to use XSLT or other scripting languages like Python to do what you want, but you can probably use the DITA Open Toolkit instead. If you use a late-model version of the DITA OT (like 3.4), try the Normalized DITA output. You get this by using the `dita` transtype. The command line would look something like this:

```
dita-ot-3.4>bin\dita --input=mymap.ditamap --format=dita
```

So if you have an input map that looks like this:

```
<map>
  <title>normalize map</title>
  <mapref keyref="api1"/>
  <keydef keys="api1" href="sub.ditamap" format="ditamap"></keydef>
</map>
```

And `sub.ditamap` looks like this:

```
<map>
  <title>submap</title>
  <topicref href="api-syntax/api-syntax.dita"/>
</map>
```

It will output something like this:

```
<map cascade="merge">
  <title>normalize map</title>
  <topicref href="api-syntax/api-syntax.dita" type="concept">
    <topicmeta>
      <navtitle>API Syntax</navtitle>
      <linktext>API Syntax</linktext>
    </topicmeta>
  </topicref>

  <keydef href="api-syntax/api-syntax.dita" processing-role="resource-only" type="concept">
    <topicmeta>
      <navtitle>API Syntax</navtitle>
      <linktext>API Syntax</linktext>
    </topicmeta>
  </keydef>
</map>
```

You can get rid of the `<keydef>` element.